# Gatsby File System Route API: unique page for every array item

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphql, gatsby, jamstack

In Gatsby I have nodes with values that contain arrays (from Airtable):

```
"edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "data": {
              "Name": "Simon",
              "Projects": [
                "Mainsite", "Backend"
              ],
              "Locations": [
                "UK", "USA"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
...
```

When I use Gatsby's [File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/) to create dynamic pages (eg `{airtable.data__Projects}.js`), then pages are created for each array used in each node, eg `/projects/mainsite-backend/`.

How do I get each item in each array in each node to have its own page, eg `/projects/mainsite` and `/projects/backend`?

Comment: [According to the maintainer](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/26375#discussioncomment-722996), it is a limitation that you can't generate dynamic routes on non-top-level data (i.e. you have to be able to query it via the 'all' prefix, like 'allMdx' or 'allSite').

Answer (score 0):

The double underscore (`__`) notation that you are using in `{airtable.data__Projects}.js` I think it's creating a undesired route. According to the docs:

> Using `__` (double underscore) you signify that you want to access a
> nested field on a node.
> You can nest as deep as necessary, e.g.
> `src/pages/products/{Product.fields__date__createdAt}.js` generates the
> following query:
>
> ```
> allProduct {
>   nodes {
>     id # Gatsby always queries for id
>     fields {
>       date {
>         createdAt
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In your case, I think you are trying to do `/projects/{airtable.data.Projects}.js`.

Alternatively (and depending on your specifications) you can create a nested JSON structure inside `Projects` using a `name` field (what will hold your `Mainsite` and `Backend` values) and suit like like `src/pages/projects/{Project.name}.js`